# Onedrive information management policy

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

We have a user who receives following information:
[image: excel error]

Can anyone tell me where this can come from. We have no retention policies set up on onedrive.
User has this on some office files, but not all. Can't really find a pattern.
If i create a new file, it does not have this error. 
I have no idea where this comes from

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely a retention policy setup somewhere.  In [office365 admin center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/retention-policies) go to security & compliance>data governance>retention.  If the ArchiveExpiration policy isn't listed there then it could be at the [sharepoint site level](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-and-apply-information-management-policies-eb501fe9-2ef6-4150-945a-65a6451ee9e9) depending on what your environment has setup and is using.

The reason you don't see this on a new file and the pattern you're missing is the retention policy is setup to look at files with a last modified date greater than 6 months. If you sort by last modified in explorer and find files that have a date greater than 6 months, and fall under the directory, this policy will be applied.

Comment: Hi Arpan, It's only showing on files that have been shared to the user. Shouldn't the policy see that as 'new' files?

Comment: Sorry Stack's notifications weren't setup for my account.  The way the policy works is by looking at modified date, and by modified it means the content of the file not the permissions.  If you share a file with someone it changes the permissions to the file, not the content, so it doesn't change the "modified date" attribute of the file.  Hope that helps :-)